# laravel php pbkdf2 login authentication

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hash, pbkdf2

I have a existing table with hash pasword using hash_pbkdf2. For user registration, it success insert into mysql

```
$string = mcrypt_create_iv(24, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$salt = strtoupper(bin2hex($string));
$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $data['password'], $string, 1000, 24, true);
$hash = strtoupper(bin2hex($hash));

return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'hashedpassword' => $hash,
    'salt' => $salt,
]);
```

I having trouble to log in using it. here is my code

```
$found_salt = DB::table('users')->where('email', 'sicksand@gmail.com')->first();
$salt = $found_salt->salt;

echo "Salt : ".$salt."<br>";
$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", "password", $salt, 1000, 24, true);
$hash = strtoupper(bin2hex($hash));

$userlogin = [
    'email' => "icksand@gmail.com",
    'hashedpassword' => $hash
];  
echo "Hash : ".$hash."<br>";

if(Auth::attempt($userlogin)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "not success";
}
```

The salt value is the same but the hash value does not match. Hoping someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code block you salt your password with the value of $string instead of $salt, but store $salt to the database.

So I think you need to change this in your first code block:

`$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $data['password'], $string, 1000, 24, true);`
to
`$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $data['password'], $salt, 1000, 24, true);`